# Peer-peer mutal SSL authentication in .Net using socket communication

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, x509certificate2

I had to do a mutual SSL authentication for peer-peer communication not localhost. I am doing this using Microsoft.Net Socket Communication Class along with SslStream class having ValidateServerCertificate and ValidateClientCertificate callbacks.

For this i have created self signed certificates comprising of one root certificate a server certificate and a client certificate.Below are the commands i am using for generating the same.

**Root**
->makecert.exe -n "CN=abc.com" -r -pe -a sha512 -len 4096 -cy authority -sv RootCert.pvk RootCert.cer
->pvk2pfx -pvk RootCert.pvk -spc RootCert.cer -pfx RootCert.pfx -po test123

**Server**
->makecert.exe -pe -n "CN=abc.com" -a sha512 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic RootCert.cer -iv RootCert.pvk -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv ServerCert.pvk ServerCert.cer
->pvk2pfx -pvk ServerCert.pvk -spc ServerCert.cer -pfx ServerCert.pfx -po test123

**Client**
->makecert.exe -pe -n "CN=abc.com" -a sha512 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -ic RootCert.cer -iv RootCert.pvk -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv ClientCert.pvk ClientCert.cer
->pvk2pfx -pvk ClientCert.pvk -spc ClientCert.cer -pfx ClientCert.pfx -po test123

After generating all the required certificates i am adding them to mmc console as you have explained above. 
To check for mutual authentication i am using **X509Certificate2** class, while doing this in **SslPolicyErrors** i am encountering error stating **RemoteCertificate Name Mismatch**

I know this is a long shot but can anyone give me any pointers on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys if you are still facing the same issues as that i have posted please follow the below link.
Our team worked on it and we found the below solution, hope it helps.

[SSL mutual authentication Certificate issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51149679-106b-47ac-9898-3ba9467a08aa/sslstream-mutual-authentication-client-certificate-is-null-at-server?forum=netfxbcl)